# Using \ifx in a macro

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to make a macro that checks if the two arguments have the same string using `\ifx`. But I observed seemingly inconsistent behavior. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\argA}{abc}
\newcommand{\argB}{abc}
\newcommand{\argC}{abcd}

\def\compA#1#2{
    \ifx #1 #2
    Same
    \else
    Different
    \fi
}

% This gives 'Same'
\ifx \argA \argB
Same
\else
Different
\fi

% This gives 'Different'
\ifx \argA \argC
Same
\else
Different
\fi

% This gives 'Different'    
\compA{\argA}{\argB}

% This gives 'Different'
\compA{\argA}{\argC}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why `\compA{\argA}{\argB}` gives `Different`. I looked for similar questions to this problem in TSE in vain. What's happening in this code?

**Update**:

After fixing the issue, I run `\compA{abc}{abc}` but the result was `Different`. What can be the solution to this issue?

**Update 2**:
I found that the following code works.

```
\def\comp#1#2{
    \def\tempA{#1}
    \def\tempB{#2}
    \ifx \tempA\tempB
    Same
    \else
    Different
    \fi
}

\comp{abc}{abc} % Same
\comp{abc}{abcd} % Different
```

But I wonder this is an efficient way to solve this issue. Can I call using `\def` inside the macro *tokenization*?

Comment: You're comparing `\argA` with the space token you have between `#1` and `#2` in the body of the definition.

Comment: @egreg I removed the space and confirmed it works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @egreg I tried `\ifx {#1}{#2}`. Does this compare `{` with `#1`?

Comment: Yes: `\ifx` compares the next two tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When TeX processes your `\compA` macro it replaces `\compA{\argA}{\argB}` with the defined replacement text, which is

```
\ifx \argA • \argB • Same • \else Different • \fi
```

according to your definition, where `•` denotes a space token (the other spaces are left for clarity and aren't in the resulting token list after the first level expansion).

So `\ifx` compares `\argA` with a space token and they're different.

Here's the fixed code:

```
\def\compA#1#2{%
    \ifx #1#2%
    Same%
    \else
    Different%
    \fi
}
```

The spaces (or endlines) after macros are ignored during tokenization; endlines *count as spaces*.

This is why `\ifx \argA \argB` returns true, because there is *no* space token behind `\argA` after tokenization.

---

The second code you present should be treated similarly:

```
\def\comp#1#2{%
    \def\tempA{#1}%
    \def\tempB{#2}%
    \ifx \tempA\tempB
    Same%
    \else
    Different%
    \fi
}
```

if you don't want spaces to pop in your document when you don't expect them, like the Spanish Inquisition.

Comment: Thank you! Are `%`s really mandatory for this code? I know what `%` is meant for but I run it without `%`s but it still works as it should.

Comment: @Hermis14 Yes, if you don't want “unexpected“ space to pop in your documents.

Comment: I am sorry but I have one more related question updated in the OP. Would you help?

Comment: @Hermis14 The code is correct up to missing `%` characters, but depending on what you're really wanting to do, there may be better methods.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try not to miss `%`. I am not used to that now :)